Probability of first success in n tries in 2 step process?
Suppose I have a process with 2 steps. The first step has probability of success $p_1$ and the second step has probability of success $p_2$.  I only attempt the second step if I succeed in the first step. What is the probability of achieving your first two consecutive successes (i.e. both first and second step succeed) in $n$ tries? Each attempt is a "try" regardless of if it's the first or second step.
For example, in the case where I fail the first step, succeed in the first step, fail the second step, succeed in the first step, succeed in the second step = FSFSS the number of tries is 5 = length of the string of successes and failures.
How would you go about working out your probability of getting your first 2 consecutive successes within $n$ tries?
Probability of first success in second step in 2 tries = P(2)=$p_1*p_2$
Probability of first success in second step in 3 tries = P(3)=$(1-p_1)*p_1*p_2$
Probability of first success in second step within n tries:
$G(n) = P(2)+P(3)...+P(n)$. Can anyone work out a way to compute for G(n)?

This is not clear.  What is a try?  What is a success?  As stated, the first success couldn't possibly occur on the second step since I need to get a success on the first step before ever even trying step $#2$.

My best guess:  A "try" mean a full round of the game.  That is, first we attempt step $#1$ and then, if we manage that first step, we attempt step $#2$.  Thus the possible out comes of a single try are:  $F, SF, SS$ where $F$ stands for Fails and $S$ for Success.  You are then asking for the probability that the first $SS$  appears on the $n^{th}$ trial.  Is that correct?

This is actually a real world example from the video game torchlight infinite where both the first step and second step each cost resources to perform. Both the first step and second steps are each their own "Try." F = "1 try", SF = "2 tries", SS =2 try, FSS = "3 tries", etc. The information I wrote before and the recursive relationship makes it clear

Still confused.  I suggest you write out a clear example or two in your post.  To be clear, suppose it take me four rounds to get a success in step $#2$ and my sequence is $F, SF, SF, SS$.  How many "tries" do you score that as?  Is it $4$ or is $7$ or is it something else?

FSFSFSS =7 tries = length of the string of successes and failures.

Again, I suggest writing this out in your post.  I don't think anyone can figure it out from what you wrote.

I don't think you can jump from $n=3$ to arbitrary $n$ as easily as you think. Once you get to larger $n$, there are many permutations of how the previous $n-2$ steps could have gone and each may have a different probability. The only thing you know for sure is that the previous $n-2$ steps end on $F$ and does not contain $SS$ as a substring

We have a recursive relationship relating P(n) and P(n-2). But yeah may be hard to get a closed from solution

It is a linear recurrence so there is a closed form expression for $P(n)$, but the sum of $n$ of them might be messier

Correction:  I misread your recursion. it is not correct.  To compute $P(n)$ recursively, you know that try $n-1$ must have been a step $#1$ Success and that you hadn't previously seen an $SS$ pair.  All $(1-P(n-2))$ tells you is that you did not win on try $n-2$, but of course you could have won a whole lot earlier than that.  Thus your recursion should reference $G(n-2)$ or something equivalent.  That's a whole lot messier.

ah, you're right. removed that part.

I actually edited the problem to better reflect the real world conditions. Makes it harder to approach, though

There's a "simple" summation solution.  In order to win on try $n$ I must have a step $#1$ success on try $n-1$ and before that I must have had $i$ rounds of type $SF$ and $n-2-2i$ rounds of type $F$ for some $i$.  For a fixed $i$ you can write out the probability of that and then you sum over $i$.  Won't be nice.

If probabilities of sucees for the two stages are different, why is $(1-P_2)$ also not entering the equations, which makes the whole thing even messier

Sketch:
A good recursion can be achieved by consider the possible outcomes of the first round.  If $n>2$ then the first round must be of type $F$ or $SF$.  That is, either you fail on Step $\#1$ in which case the game resets or you succeed on $\#1$ but fail on $\#2$ in which case the game again resets.  It follows that $$P(n)=(1-p_1)P(n-1)+p_1(1-p_2)P(n-2)$$
This can be solved in the usual way to get a weighted sum of two exponentials.  In turn, those exponentials could be summed to get the cumulative distribution, though I expect the result is messy.
Worth remarking:  this is akin to the definition of the Fibonacci numbers as the number of ways to climb $n$ stairs given that you can either go $1$ or $2$ at a time.
I suggest:  implement this for some fixed choice of $p_1, p_2$.  See what it looks like.

thanks. this approach would solve the original problem I posted with some effort. However, I revised the problem statement a lot to better match the real world problem.

In any case, this method is very easy to implement numerically and, with reasonable choices of $p_i$, you expect $P(n)\to 0$ quite rapidly.  Thus, as a practical matter, you can probably answer anything you need to answer this way without worrying about a closed formula.

If we let $F(n)$ be the probability that we do not obtain a success within $n$ tries, then $F$ also satisfies the above recurrence, and the cdf is given by $G(n)=1-F(n)$.

@MaxChien  Good point

Anybody knows that the probability of success within budget is zero.

this makes computing easy and I guess is more useful than the closed form solution.

When finding the probability that the first double success is on the $n$th turn we know that the last two turns have probability $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively.
It now remains to find the probability that we to complete $n-2$ turns without a win. Suppose we pass the first round $x$ times, this means we will fail the second round $x$ times and fail the first round $(n-2)-2x$ times. This gives us a probability of $p_1^x (1-p_2)^x (1-p_1)^{n-2-2x}$. However, this does not count the numbers of way to arrange the first round fails and first round successes. Note that the second round fails are chosen by the placement of the first round successes.
We can then work out that given $x$ first round successes there are $\begin{pmatrix} n-2-x \\ x \end{pmatrix}$ ways for this to happen and each one has a probability of $p_1^x (1-p_2)^x (1-p_1)^{n-2-2x} p_1p_2$.
Hence the probability that your first double success is on turn $n$ with $x+1$ first round successes ($x$ in the first $n-2$ turns and 1 at the second to last turn) is $\begin{pmatrix} n-2-x \\ x \end{pmatrix} p_1^x (1-p_2)^x (1-p_1)^{n-2-2x} p_1p_2$. We can then sum over x to get:
$$P(n) = \sum_{x=0}^{(n-2)/2} \begin{pmatrix} n-2-x \\ x \end{pmatrix} p_1^x (1-p_2)^x (1-p_1)^{n-2-2x} p_1p_2$$
Then if we want to find $G(k)$ we can sum $P(n)$ for $2\le n \le k$.
$$ G(k) = \sum_{n=2}^k \sum_{x=0}^{(n-2)/2} \begin{pmatrix} n-2-x \\ x \end{pmatrix} p_1^x (1-p_2)^x (1-p_1)^{n-2-2x} p_1p_2 $$

This was an answer to your original question, but I did not see your edit when I wrote this.

I reverted the question to original form to make useful to people/since you answered the question. Thank you.

I gave the answer to the recursion form bc it's so easy to compute but thank you. I know I orginally asked for the closed form solution.
